# intermittment RequestFactory error in Eclipse

Tags: android, google-app-engine, requestfactory

I have been using RequestFactory successfully for many months in my AppEngine connected Android project. Occasionally, though, I have a problem in the file in which I subclass RequestFactory

```
public interface MyRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {
    ...
}
```

**Eclipse gives me a red X** on the line "public interface..." and the error I get is shown below. (Note this is not a run-time, it's just in the Eclipse window while I'm editing)

The strange thing is, I usually can do a few Project->Clean and edit the code a few times, never making any actual code change, then "Save" and the problem always goes away.  This time it's stuck though.

Any ideas?

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.internal.AptCompilationParticipant.addJava6GeneratedFile(AptCompilationParticipant.java:272)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeProcessingEnvImpl.addNewUnit(IdeProcessingEnvImpl.java:132)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.filer.IdeJavaSourceOutputStream.close(IdeJavaSourceOutputStream.java:72)
>   at   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:319) at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:148) at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233) at
>   java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:265) at
>   java.io.PrintWriter.close(PrintWriter.java:312) at
>   com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DeobfuscatorBuilder.visitType(DeobfuscatorBuilder.java:146)
>   at
>   com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DeobfuscatorBuilder.visitType(DeobfuscatorBuilder.java:43)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl.accept(TypeElementImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:139)
>   at
>   com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ScannerBase.scan(ScannerBase.java:63)
>   at
>   com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.State.executeJobs(State.java:248)
>   at
>   com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfValidator.process(RfValidator.java:83)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:139)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:121)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManag
>   er.java:159) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorMan
>   ager.java:134) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:813)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:432)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:364)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.compile(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:329)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:301)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.build(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:134)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildDeltas(JavaBuilder.java:265)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:193)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager 
>   $2.run(BuildManager.java:728) at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager 
>   $1.run(BuildManager.java:292) at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known Eclipse bug.  The only solution I've found is to restart eclipse.  Sometimes I must compile without annotations and then restart.

Comment: Wow! Someone else has seen the problem! Thanks!  I haven't seen this with the Eclipse Juno.

Comment: What you mean without annotations? Do you mean annotation processing? If i run it without annotation precessing, it works. But as soon as I activate annotation processing again, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting or disabling annotation processing didn't work in my case. 
I had two request factories (in different projects!) with this error.

- myReqFacA extends RequestFactory
- myReqFacB extends RequestFactory

I solved the problem by deleting one of the request factory interfaces. Fortunately the interface wasn't needed any more.

But after one day i have the same problem again!

Comment: yes this is just the kind of thing that would often see.  After all is said and done, I'm not sure RequestFactory is worth all the trouble.  Anyway,  I just keep doing the same thing: do some "fake" edits of the RequestFactory subclass and some project "cleans", and usually it goes away after a few of those.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. The work around I used is to rename the RequestFactory subclass name (Refactor->Rename). I changed the other part of the subclass, it does not work. After successful compile, just rename it back to what used to be.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with the RequestFactory from GWT and I solved it deleting the folder "gwt-unitCache" and later compiling the project again (Project -> Clean...)

Most probably for android it is necessary to delete some kind of generated folder and compile the project again.